# RSelenium: failing to send input to text box

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

This script is entirely working apart from the input text into the longitude and latitude fields, which for some reason are not responsive. Could you please help figuring out how to fix this?

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"), chromever = "78.0.3904.105")
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$open()

remote_driver$navigate("https://climateknowledgeportal.worldbank.org/download-data#download-data-projections-tab")

type_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'futureType')
variable <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'variablesFutu')
longitude <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'class', value = 'longitude')
latitude <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'latitude')
time_period <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'futuTimeSeries')
statistic <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'statistic')
scenario <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'scenario')

type_element$sendKeysToElement(list("CMIP5"))
variable$sendKeysToElement(list("cdd65"))
time_period$sendKeysToElement(list("2040-2059"))
statistic$sendKeysToElement(list("manom"))
scenario$sendKeysToElement(list("rcp45"))

latitude$sendKeysToElement(list("30")) # does not work
longitude$sendKeysToElement(list("30")) # does not work 

button_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = "downloadProjectionsBtn")
button_element$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert with RSelenium but I see you are identifying latitude as

```
latitude <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'latitude')
```

, when id is in fact *latitudeProj*

All your fields are lists, except latitude and longitude, but you seem to be sending keys to these two as list item? If you try:
`latitude$sendKeysToElement("abc")` would it accept it?